# How do I use async await with map in the mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
 const mapLoop = async _ => {
        console.log('Start')
      
        const promises = books.forEach( async (book) => {
            const ownerInfos = await User.find({_id: book.Owner})  
            return ownerInfos;
            
        })
      
        const ownerInformation = await Promise.all([promises])
        console.log(ownerInformation)
      
        console.log('End')
      }
    
 mapLoop();
```

The books variable consist of objects each with key value pair of nameBook, editionBook, _id, and Owner(which is an id). What I want to do here is find the owner of the book by the id stored in the value "Owner". However, the ownerInformation variable is printing undefined.

Comment: Replace `.forEach` with `.map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach()` is for performing an action on each array element and does not return you a new array. It also does not respect `async/await`. So, your next line is reached before any of your database calls are actually [completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop), not that it would have mattered anyway. With your `promises` being undefined : `await Promise.all([undefined])` returns `[undefined]`

Try mapping the books array directly into the promises array. Now, promises is an array of `promises` and you can use `Promise.all` with `await` to get your result.

```
const promises = books.map(book => User.find({_id: book.Owner});  
           
const ownerInformation = await Promise.all(promises)
console.log(ownerInformation)
```

But, there is *an optimization* you can make where you only have to make one DB query that has all your `_id`s. This uses the [$in()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator, used to search for a field value in a given array:

```
const bookOwnerIds = books.map(book => book.Owner);
const ownerInformation  = await User.find({'_id': { $in : [bookOwnerIds] });
```

Also, please check if your `.bookOwner` is the correct format as a mongoose object id would expect. If not, you will probably have to use something like `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(book.Owner)` in both of the above cases.

Comment: Sure, please consider upvoting/green ticking this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

1. `forEach` doesn't return anything (it mutates an array *in place*) so `promises` will *always* be undefined. Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead which returns a new array.
2. There's no need for the `map` callback to be async, and there's no need to `await` the `find` process. Simply return the promise.
3. `promises` will now be an array so you don't need to wrap it in a new array in `Promise.all`.

   ```
   const promises = books.map(book => {
     return User.find({ _id: book.Owner });
   });

   const ownerInformation = await Promise.all(promises);

   console.log(ownerInformation);
   ```